# The function of the syntax len

Tags: python

```
maxQuestions = 3
for question in firstQuestions:
    answer1 = input(question)
    while(len(answer1) == 0 or (answer1 != "yes" and answer1 != "no")):
            answer1 = input("You may only input yes or no \n" + question)
    if answer1 ==  "yes":
            print("")
    else:
        if booleanArray[firstQuestions.index(question)] == True:
            answer2 = input(firstQuestionsAnswers[firstQuestions.index(question)])
            while(len(answer2) == 0):
                 answer2 = input("You must input an answer \n" + firstQuestionsAnswers[firstQuestions.index(question)])
            answerToQuestion = finalAnswers(answer2, firstQuestions.index(question))
            print(secondQuestionAnswers[firstQuestions.index(question)] + answerToQuestion)
        else:
            print(firstQuestionsAnswers[firstQuestions.index(questionn)])
```

I'm just a beginner. What does len do in this situation. Are there any problems or disadvantages using the len syntax.

Comment: `len` gets the length of the object.

Comment: The major disadvantage of not using the "len syntax" is that you can't get this program to work without it, as you don't know the length of the input.

Comment: Don't use `foo == True`; it is exactly equivalent to `foo` by itself in a Boolean context.

Answer (score 2):

Code like this:

```
if len(answer1) == 0
```

Is more typically written in Python as:

```
if not answer1:
```

The boolean evaluation of a string is False when a string is empty, and True otherwise.  So it's both more concise and more efficient to write the second form.

Comment: In this case there is no need for `len()` or another falsey check, simply check `if answer1 not in {'yes', 'no'}`